# String comparison equivalents

Tags: c#, .net, string, clr, string-comparison

I believe these 2 lines are equivalent but after running into a strange issue I no longer believe this to be the case.

```
String mimeType = context.Request.ContentType;
(String.Compare("text/xml", mimeType, true) == 0))
```

is the same as :

```
context.Request.ContentType.ToLower().Equals("text/xml")
```

Are their implementations in the CLR any different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not completely equivalent;  see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx).

Here is the correct way to do a case insensitive comparison:

```
bool areSame = str1.Equals(str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

This way will also be more efficient becasue it doesn't allocate a separate string for the lowercase copy.

Comment: This will work for 99.999% of the cases, but might fail some times. See `The Turkish-I Problem` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx

Comment: @SLaks: I'm not sure what the point was, but `OrdinalIgnoreCase` does _not_ solve the Turkish-I problem.

Comment: You *should not* "solve" the Turkish I problem when comparing mime-types!

Comment: this answer is not null safe. ie if str1 is null

Comment: @Simon: Correct.  `String.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` does.

Answer (score 6):

They are not equivalent, and ToLower/ToUpper may have some localization issues.  The way to compare two strings without case-sensitivity (considering one of the strings may be null, which is why I don't like the str1.Equals method) is the static String.Equals method:

```
bool areEqual = String.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Preferred version because of safe `null` handling, but Gonzalo's comment to the other answer applies here as well, and should be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers (@SLaks, @Serhio), I also feel obligated to point out that .ToLower() generates *another* string. Compare does not as far as I know. Excessive string generation in an app can come back to bite you in terms of memory usage and performance if it is in frequently called code.

Answer (score 0):

the implementation of Compare(string, string, boolean) in .NET:

```
public static int Compare(string strA, string strB, bool ignoreCase)
{
    if (ignoreCase)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(strA, strB, CompareOptions.None);
}
```

and Equals

```
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
public bool Equals(string value)
{
    if ((value == null) && (this != null))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return EqualsHelper(this, value);
}
```

So, is **NOT** the same thing.